# Mock pg using jest

Tags: node.js, testing, jestjs, pg

```
 const add = async (params) => {
    const { tenant_guid } = params;
    const { add } = mdlRoles;
    const taskResult = await db[`cmp_${tenant_guid}`].task(
      async (tx) => tx.one(add, params),
    );
    return taskResult;
  };
```

this is what i tries but its wrong
the db in this is a connectio nand mdlroles the module where query is placed with the name add.

```
const db = require("../../adapters/pgsql");
const MdlRoles = require("../../models/MdlRoles");
const SvcRoles = require("../SvcRoles");

// Mock the database and the models
jest.mock("../../adapters/pgsql", () => ({
  cmp_abc123: {
    task: jest.fn(),
  },
}));

jest.mock("../../models/MdlRoles", () => ({
  add: "INSERT INTO roles(name, description) VALUES($name, $description) RETURNING id",
}));

describe("Roles Service test", () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  test("add Roles to a database", async () => {
    const params = {
      name: "John Doe",
      description: "Admin",
      tenant_guid: "abc123",
    };
    const expectedTaskResult = { id: 1 };

    // Mock the database transaction to return the expected value
    // Mock the database transaction to return the expected value
    db[`cmp_${params.tenant_guid}`].task.mockImplementation((callback) =>
      callback({
        one: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(expectedTaskResult),
      })
    );

    const svcRoles = SvcRoles({
      db,
      mdlRoles: MdlRoles,
    });
    const result = await svcRoles.add(params);

    expect(result).toEqual(expectedTaskResult);

    // Check that the mock transaction was called
    expect(db[`cmp_${params.tenant_guid}`].task).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      expect.any(Function)
    );
    expect(db[`cmp_${params.tenant_guid}`].task.mock.calls[0][0]).not.toThrow();
    expect(
      db[`cmp_${params.tenant_guid}`].task.mock.calls[0][0]
    ).toBeInstanceOf(Function);
    const tx = db[`cmp_${params.tenant_guid}`].task.mock.calls[0][0]();
    expect(tx.one).toHaveBeenCalledWith(MdlRoles.add, [
      params.name,
      params.description,
    ]);
  });
});
```

this is my sample code i want to mock db, that is database connection and add, that is a query to return a result in taskresult. db is a database connection.

Comment: update i am now just unable to resolve this error     const taskResult = await db[`cmp_${tenant_guid}`].task(async tx => tx.one(add, params));
                                                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'one')